# getting node's URL from drupal services module

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-7

I'm writing an external app that loads it's data from a drupal site, the site implemented "services" module which returns JSON representation of a node and (almost) all of it's data.
the one thing the service does not return is the url of the requested node,
so I'm calling this:

> [domain]/rest/mynode/ffad3c26-e684-4cca-9c4b-16334f9f3dc1.json

and getting this:

> {
>
> > vid: "2087",
> >
> > uid: "67133de7-9755-424d-b45b-c4bbf41cb00e",
> >
> > title: "PD300",
> >
> > log: "Updated by FeedsNodeProcessor",
> >
> > status: "1",
> >
> > comment: "0",
> >
> > promote: "0",
> >
> > sticky: "0",
> >
> > vuuid: "097f43ef-e22c-4f35-b74d-02b8e8ac5895",
> >
> > nid: "2087",
> >
> > type: "product",
> >
> > language: "en"... and some more

I also need the url for the current node so I can link back to it from the app, any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to concatenate in your application the string something like that:

URL= "[domain]"."/node/"."{nid}"

Comment: this works, but the nodes has custom URLs field on the Drupal site, and I need that field

Comment: you may need node path alias.